# One single figure for multiple boxplots from single dataframe with several variables

Tags: ggplot2, raster, boxplot

I recently extracted values from multiple rasters and as a output I have a dataframe where the columns are the variables with respectively values for each row.
I want to build boxplots of each variable in single plot.

I use :

```
library(raster)
wc <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)
values <- sampleRandom(wc, 100)    
boxplot(values)
```

[image]

The graphic is very bad. I need one figure with boxs for each raster and with each their own scale

Any suggestion to make a good graphic in a simply way ?

Here is

Answer (score 0):

Reprex a bad boxplot

```
library(raster)
wc <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)
values <- sampleRandom(wc, 100)    
boxplot(values)
```